# Demosaic data stored in TIFF

Tags: raw, demosaicing

Is there a relatively easy to use tool that will allow me to demosaic some raw data stored in a TIFF file (not a standard raw file such as DNG, NEF, etc.), assuming a Bayer pattern?  The TIFF contains no metadata, so should be possible to specify any necessary additional information separately.

Comment: Use case: same as [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41948/10147).

Comment: Do you have three different color layers and are trying to demosaic and combine, or an already combined file with some patterns you are trying to remove?

Comment: @PatrickHurley I have a single channel which looks like no. 2 [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Colorful_spring_garden_Bayer.png).  I'm looking for a tool that'll reconstruct no. 4.  I'm not looking to implement it myself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming for image processing, not about photography.

Comment: @mattdm It's not about programming, nor about image processing methods.  The question is asking for a software tool to do something, like many other questions on this site.

Comment: "To do _something_" is the key. This site is for questions about photography, not the arbitrary set of all questions that might have to do with digital image files. It doesn't mean anything bad about the question in an absolute sense that it doesn't fit with that theme. It's just not the right place for it.

Comment: @mattdm Then instead of voting to close, you can vote to migrate it to the right place ... the problem came up in a practical application to photography, so I thought it's more likely I'll find an answer here than on DSP.SE, as more people here would want to do the same thing here.  Looking at the other questions on this site I don't see why this is clearly off topic if asking for say noise reduction software is not off topic.

Comment: No,  there is no direct migration path to other sites from here. Voting to close is the appropriate thing. We can take this up on http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com if you like.

Comment: Or if you want to edit the photo to make it more relevant,  that's good too.

Comment: I can migrate this to any stackexchange site in the network, if there is a more appropriate place for this. StackOverflow doesn't seem like quite the right place...

Answer (score 1):

Most raw formats are actually stored in .tiff containers.  They're simply proprietary data in a .tiff container.

Three thoughts for you for what you are trying to do:

1) Try Dave Coffin's [DCRaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dcraw) package, without or with a GUI front-end.

2) You could also read the file into Photoshop as a (.raw) format; it would come in as a single plane and require manipulation to be converted to RGB.

3) If you are or know a programmer, it would not be hard to parse this from a simple TIFF file without any metadata (perhaps an hour's work or so).

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION FOUND: Change the extension of your file from TIF to DNG (for example "image.tif" would become "image.dng"). RawTherapee will now read it like any other raw file and demosaic it however you like!

Comment: Really?  Do TIFF and DNG use the same underlying format?  Can't try til next week, but I am curious.

Comment: DNG is based on the TIFF format, but I don't really know much more than that. I was getting desperate for a solution to this problem so I tried this trick because it had worked for me in the past with certain video file extensions, some of which are "containers" of other formats. I was very surprised that this worked.