# Is it possible to read one bayer raw data steam file using RawTherapee?

Tags: raw, rawtherapee, bayer

I have one bayer raw file which contains only pixel values in bayer pattern and no metadata.The bayer pattern is known.
Is it possible to the file using RawTherapee?
The following link provides some information:
http://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Adding_Support_for_New_Raw_Formats
The information is not enough to solve my problem.

Comment: `dcraw -I` may do what you need.  I haven't tested it.

Comment: You might also try to pack it in a TIFF container and rename to DNG - see https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/93668/59825

Comment: Does TIFF container include the bayer pattern information?

Answer (score 1):

RawTherapee uses an embedded copy of the [DCRAW](https://www.dechifro.org/dcraw/) utility to read and decode the RAW file ([original source code](https://www.dechifro.org/dcraw/dcraw.c)). So, you need to add support for your file format here.

Comment: Is it possible to support the format without modifying source code?

Comment: The source code of DCRAW is pretty straightforward. You might be able to rewrite some parts to use configuration files, but I doubt that you can support all idiosyncrasies of all RAW formats in configuration, without writing most code twice: as source code and as configuration file. It is much easier to keep it all in one place, i.e in source code.